# rdiff-backup-like storage on Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, rsync, rdiff-backup

I am looking for a way to store files in Artifactory repository in a storage efficient way and upload/download difference between local version and remote in order to save disk space, bandwidth and time.

There are two good utilities which works in this way `rsync` and `rdiff-backup`. <sub>Sure there are others.</sub>

Is there a way to organize something similar with Artifactory stack?

---

What is rsync:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>          Rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool.  It can  copy  locally,
>          to/from another host over any remote shell, or to/from a remote rsync daemon.  It offers
>          a large number of options that control every aspect of  its  behavior  and  permit  very
>          flexible  specification  of  the  set  of  files  to  be  copied.   **It is famous for its
>
>          delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data  sent  over  the  network  by
>
>          sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the des-
>
>          tination**.  Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved  copy  com-
>          mand for everyday use.

Answer (score 0):

JFrog CLI includes a functionality called "Sync Deletes", allowing to sync files between the local file system and Artifactory. 
This functionality is supported by both the "jfrog rt upload" and "jfrog rt download" commands. Both commands accept the optional --sync-deletes flag.

When uploading, the value of this flag specofies a path in Artifactory, under which to sync the files after the upload. After the upload, this path will include only the files uploaded during this upload operation. The other files under this path will be deleted.

The same goes for downloading, but this time, the value of the --sync-deletes flag specifies a path in the local file system, under which files which had not been downloaded from Artifactory are deleted.

Read more this in the following link:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

Comment: Does this command calculate difference between upload/download or it works with full-size files?

Comment: Not sure I fully understood the question. Let me know if this answers your question. The command deletes files on the target, if they do not exist on the source. The delete is performed following a download or upload. The comparison is checksum based.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But jfrog cli does not do what rsync does. I updated question with rsync description. And highlighted its main feature.